# How many bytes are IV and Keys for AES?

Tags: c#, encryption, aescryptoserviceprovider

I'm using AESCryptoServiceProvider in C#/.Net Framework and I'm wondering how large, in bytes, the IV and Keys are. I'm pretty sure that this class follows the specifications of AES so if anyone has any ideas, I'd be happy to hear it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The IV size is 16 bytes, and the default key size is 32 (16 and 24 are also allowed)  You can use the [BlockSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.blocksize.aspx), [KeySize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.keysize.aspx), [LegalBlockSizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalblocksizes.aspx), and [LegalKeySizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalkeysizes.aspx) properties, respectively.  The API provides the value in bits.

Comment: Thanks! I scrolled through the docs like 15 times and I didn't realize that BlockSize and KeySize were properties >_>

Comment: So, it's correct to assume that AESCryptoServiceProvider defaults to AES-256? and not AES-128?